# magento - how to add property to eav model when is inialized

Tags: magento, model, entity-attribute-value

i'm not able to add a property in _data array() to EAV model (extended Product Model) when *it is initialized*, for example by a collection call (Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')).

I try to extend _construct() with setValue(), but not work and here _data is empty!

**When _data is filled?**

When i have the product model with _data setted and i can manipulate this *in initialization phase*?

I don't want an attribute setted in db, because this attribute is dynamic.

thx for replies! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do it in the `_load_after` observer.

Comment: ok, now i try!
Do you know how collection model load data in its items?
It load its when it's called, but which method/class are used to make this?

thx for reply!

Comment: It have its own `_load_after` observer ;-)

Comment: So for products you will need `catalog_product_load_after` and `catalog_product_collection_load_after`.

Comment: it's difficult for me entry in this logic! :(
thx very much for your help!

Comment: i look the events and i find catalog_product_collection_load_after, but don't have catalog_product_load_after....There is an model_load_after next catalog_product_collection_load_after!
What is model?!? Maybe because is an extended module of catalog_product?

I'm in catalog page.

Comment: !!!
I found the problem!
When i load product collection, it don't trigge the catalog_product_event!
If i see the object product in collection with a the same object product loaded by getModel('catalog/product') is different, also for its properties!

Answer (score 0):

What attributes are loaded and when are they loaded depends on where are you "standing" and whether or not you have the flat catalog enabled.

Generally speaking, to have an attribute loaded into a catalog/product_collection you need to specify it like this:

```
<?php
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute')
```

Comment: yes, i would to add a property to product model, that is not an attribute in db.
For this scope i've to use an observer on catalog_product_load_after event and use setData('customAttr','hello').